# having trouble looping over objects in spring MVC using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i am new to spring and JSP coding. i am simply trying to loop over an object array that was passed into my JSP from a spring controller using javascript.  The following html code works perfectly in my JSP where the model is passed from the spring controller to the jsp view.

```
<c:forEach items="${model.dataBaseManager.dataBases.get(0).institutionManager.institutions}" var="prod">
        <c:out value="${prod.name}"/> <i><br><br>
</c:forEach>
```

However, i need to loop over this array using javascript not html.  this is what i have tried:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
          alert("${model.dataBaseManager.dataBases.get(0).institutionManager.institutions.get(x).name}");
   };
```

This however just keeps popping up an alert for the first value in the array even though the x value keeps indexing.  I have tried converting the dataBaseManager to a JSON before passing it to the JSP with the same exact results. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

JSTL is server side, whereas JS is client side, in your code, the alert line is parsed on server side only for the first element i.e. `model.dataBaseManager.dataBases.get(0)`. Also here JS, `x` has no significance.

Yo may try this work around for JS.

```
<script>
var prod=[];//js array
<c:forEach items="${model.dataBaseManager.dataBases.get(0).institutionManager.institutions}" var="prod">
        prod.push("${prod.name}");// add each name one by one to js array
</c:forEach>
alert(prod.join(',')); // shows all name in one alert as csv
</script>
```

Comment: quick question:  why does alert(x) work properly inside the for loop? in other words if i put alert(x) inside the for loop, it will properly pop up 10 instances with different values of x (0-9)?